# Let $f(x)=x^2-8x+4$, where $x\in[4,\infty)$. Show that $f$ is one-to-one.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

I would like to know if this is ok.

Let $f(x)=x^2-8x+4$ with $x\in[4,\infty)$. Show that $f$ is one-to-one.

If,

$$f(a)=f(b)$$
$$a^2-8a+4=b^2-8b+4$$
$$a^2-8a=b^2-8b+4-4$$
$$a^2-8a=b^2-8b$$
$$a(a-8)=b(b-8)$$

Therefore,
$$a=b$$

Therefore,$f$ is one-to-one.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: $a(a-8)= b(b-8) \implies a=b$ has skipped steps, which are crucial to the answer. I don't think you should skip them.

Comment: Your proof doesn't use at any moment the hypothesis of $x$ being in $[4,\infty)$. That should be a red flag. It tells you that your proof is incomplete/incorrect since the statement is obviously false without that hypothesis (the graph of the function is a parabola).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$a(a-8)=b(b-8)$$

Here, it is not sufficient to conclude $a=b$, for example, $a=0, b=8$, so you need to use the domain $[4, \infty)$ to exclude the cases such as $a=0, b=8$.

> $$a^2-8a=b^2-8b$$

Go back to this step, instead, you can factor it in this way,

$$\begin{align}a^2-b^2&=8a-8b\\
\\
(a+b)(a-b)&=8(a-b)\\
\\
(a+b-8)(a-b)&=0\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: thanks <3 !!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Note $f(2)=f(6)=-8$. But you're on the right track.

$f(x)=x^2-8x+4$

$a^2-8a+4=b^2-8b+4$

$(a^2-b^2)-8(a-b)=0$

$(a-b)(a+b-8)=0$

So either $a=b$ or $a+b=8$.

Given the domain, either $a=b=4$ or $a+b>8$, so we must have $a=b$.

Alternatively $f(x)=x^2-8x+4=(x-4)^2-12$. So $f(x)$ has a minimum value of $-12$ and increases monotonically from there. $x>y \iff f(x)>f(y) $

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x>y$. By the monotonicity, we must have $f(x)>f(y)$, thus the assumption that $x>y$ leads to a contradiction. The same argument applies if we have $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x<y$. Given two quantities $x$ and $y$, either $x=y$, $x<y$ or $x>y$. The two inequalities have been ruled out leaving only equality, so a monotonic function is one to one.

Comment: thanks <3 !!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, but you cannot conclude the desired result as you did.

I would slightly change the last step to obtain:
\begin{align*}
a^{2} - 8a = b^{2} - 8b & \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} - b^{2} = 8(a - b)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a - b)(a + b) = 8(a - b)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a - b)(a + b - 8) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$\underline{\text{Intermediate Result}}$ 
**IR-1**
For $~y \geq 0,~$ the function $~g(y) = y^2~$ is strictly increasing on $~[0,\infty).$ 
**Proof**
Assume that $~0 \leq y_1 < y_2.$ 
Then $~y_2^2 - y_1^2 = (y_2 - y_1) \times (y_2 + y_1) > 0.$ 
Thus, $~y_2 > y_1 \implies y_2^2 > y_1^2.$

---

It is sufficient to show that 
$~f(x) = x^2 - 8x + 4 ~$ is strictly increasing on $[4,\infty).$

$$f(x) = (x - 4)^2 - 12.$$

Let $~y = (x-4) \implies \{ ~[4 \leq x] \iff [0 \leq y] ~\}.$

Then, setting $~g(y) = y^2,~$ you have that 
$f(x) = g(y) - 12.~$

By **IR-1**, $~g(y)~$ is strictly increasing. 
Therefore, so is $~f(x) = g(y) - 12.$